# Register and Login by Phone Number in Asp.net Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

Is it possible to don't use Email to register and login in asp.net core identity?

Users just register by mobile number and login by SMS verification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possible way is to setup identity as two factor authentication. Instead of email use username to store the mobile number. To do this set `RequireUniqueEmail = false` in ApplicationUserManager.Create.

You'll need to add your own code to retrieve the number and validate it. Make sure it always has the same format as it should match the username.

In the code where the username is verified skip the password check (since password is null), but do check the number. Send an SMS with code and continue with the flow.

You can add your own logic to create and verify the code and how long it is valid.

Comment: Is there any sample to do it?

Comment: @saeed 2FA with sms is deprecated, but the [asp.net core 1.1 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/security/authentication/2fa?view=aspnetcore-1.1) may help you.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't rely in `Username` in your application, (Like you don't show it to user ever), then you can set Username to a guid and skip the email part.

For registration,

```
var identityUser = new User
                   {
                     Username= Guid.NewGuid(),
                     PhoneNumber= phoneNumber
                   };
           
var result = await _signInManager.UserManager.CreateAsync(identityUser, user.Password);
```

For Login,

```
var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.Users
                   .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => 
                      x.NormalizedEmail == usernameParam
                   || x.PhoneNumber== usernameParam);
if (user == null)
{
    return Forbid();
}

var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, passwordParam, false);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
  //  return new TokenResponse(token, refreshToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the user's username to the user's phone number during registration.
your registration code can look like this.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser
{
    UserName = registerModel.PhoneNumber,
    Email = registerModel.Email,
    PhoneNumber = registerModel.PhoneNumber,
    FirstName = registerModel.FirstName,
    LastName = registerModel.LastName,
    SetUpComplete = false
};

var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, registerModel.Password);
```

then your login code can look like this.

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(payload.username)

//var user = await _userManager.Users.Where(x => x.Email == login.Email)
//    .Include(x => x.RefreshTokens).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

if (user == null)
    return Unauthorized("Invalid username or password");

bool checkUserPassword = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, payload.Password);

//do what ever you want here
```